# OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter vs OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter in Spring Security OAuth2 client

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

When I am trying to understand OAuth2 client, I am confused about why we have two different filters

I attempted to integrate with Github. Here are my observations

1. `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter` sound like a filter that exchanges authorization code for access token, but when I keep debug point it does not do that
2. `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` sounds somewhat like it does login somehow, but this filter exchanges auth code to access token instead of above

I'm not sure why this is the case, as the first class name implies some strong correlation to authorization code

Also, Whats is the difference between `OAuth2LoginConfigurer` & `OAuth2ClientConfigurer`

Looks like `OAuth2LoginConfigurer` configures `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter`, while `OAuth2ClientConfigurer` configures `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter`

Can someone explain what each of them does & in which scenarios they are applicable?

Thanks

Comment: Did you read Spring Security Reference? See [OAuth 2.0 Client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2client) and [OAuth 2.0 Login](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login).

Comment: Sorry.. Not yet.. Just skimmed over it to see if I can find quick pointers. But it does not talk about `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter`. Appreciate if you know what the first filter does. I'll go over the documentation in the mean time. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: That's not a good way to learn Spring Security. It is much to complicated to start with some classes. However, `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter` is the implementation of the authorization code grant type for OAuth2 clients (first link).

Comment: I have a reasonable understanding of Spring Security & have implemented Oauth2 with resource owner password grant in the past. W.r.t authorization code grant flow, `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` is handling `authentication code` -> `access token` exchange from auth server. So, not sure where `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter` fits in

Answer (score 4):

This is well documented in the Spring Security reference.

- [OAuth 2.0 Login](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login)
- [OAuth 2.0 Client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2client)

As well, in the javadoc:

- [`OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.html)
- [`OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter.html)

At a high level:

- `http.oauth2Login()` is an implementation of [OpenID Connect **Authentication** using the Authorization Code Flow](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeFlowAuth)
- `http.oauth2Client().authorizationCodeGrant()` is an implementation of [OAuth 2.0 **Authorization** Code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) grant

Comment: Thanks for your response. In short is correct to say, if the authorization server is a plain OAuth2 server, `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter` does the `authorization code -> access token` exchange. Else if the authorization server is a OpenId Connect server, `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` does the `authorization code -> access+id token` exchange?

Comment: I just tried using OAuth2 client using Github (OAuth2 server) & Keycloak (Openid complaint). In both cases, `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` is actually doing the `authorization token -> access token` exchange. Appreciate if you can help me with some basic understanding I'm missing over here. Thanks

Comment: Your understanding is pretty close but missing a couple of points. The first step to gain a better understanding is to fully understand the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Grant flow and OpenID Connect. The only way is to read the spec via the links that I have provided. After you gain that understanding, than read the `http.oauth2Login()` and `http.oauth2Client().authorizationCodeGrant()` reference docs to see how it was implemented as per spec.

Comment: The key point to understanding the main differences here is that `http.oauth2Login()` is used for Authenticating users using OpenID Connect. For example, it would be used as an alternative to `formLogin()`. And `http.oauth2Client().authorizationCodeGrant()` is used for cases where an OAuth 2.0 client requires an access token, in order to initiate a call to a protected resource, but needs to be authorized by the Resource Owner first via the Authorization Code grant.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will go over the sources & will share any future questions I might have. As of now, My understanding is still messed up (as `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` is doing the `auth code` -> `access token` exchange for both OAuth2 server & Oidc server). I will do some home work before I bug you. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter  will creates an Authentication in the SecurityContext. That is, once this filter is processed, Spring Security will mark a user has logged in and an authenticated session will be created. In contrast, the OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter does not create a new authenticated session, but it will simply store the newly fetched access token in OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository under the already authentcated user. So as Joe said, OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter is for OIDC login and OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter for OAuth2. Remember OAuth2 is not login.